# Request for Edit Access using View Access

Tags: google-drive, permissions, access-control

I have been provided with a link only to **View** a particular folder. Is it possible for me to request for **Edit Access?** If so, how can you do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1

Click the drop-down arrow on the folder name.

[image: Step 1]

### Step 2

Click on "Share".

[image: Step 2]

### Step 3

Fill in your Gmail address, and add a message for the owner of the folder, then press "Send request".

[image: Step 3]

Comment: @user0 I rejected the proposed edit because if the user only has view access, there is no "advanced" option when they click share.