# Why am I receiving access requests on my "Public on the web" Google drive folder?

Tags: google-drive, file-sharing

I've linked a variety of Google Drive folders containing public documents to my organization's website for ease of updating. These are all set to "Public on the web" as seen here:
[image]

So clearly not restricted to my organization or even someone logged in to a Google account.

However today I received an access request for this same folder:

[image]

I'm mostly paranoid that there is still some subset of users out there that this setting restricts from access, I don't want to go forward with this solution if it's going to result in someone not being able to see important information or me having to manually share a folder with strangers periodically.

It may be the case that the person has access and was confused so they sent me the request anyway.

Any advice?

Comment: They are requesting edit access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person requested edit access. They most likely did not realize that they didn't need this level of access. The process they followed was probably this:

First, they wanted to share the folder, so they went to the sharing settings for the folder:

[image: Share view-only folder]

Then, when clicking on "Share", they would have been presented with this dialogue box, and filled out the e-mail address that requested access:

[image: Request access dialogue box]

Your question is similar to one which asked the reverse: [how to request edit access, given view access](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/113121/109353).

Comment: This looks right, thanks for the response! Good to know at least someone wasn't being restricted from seeing it.